# SAS Base - Association rules matrix

Tags: matrix, sas, associations

I'm using SAS Base/ SAS Enterprise Guide and I'm stuck.
I need to create the Association Rules matrix to calculate the support, lift, confidence and other association metrics.

My table is similar to: (one line per client with all the products associated to)

```
    data test;
    input item1 item2 item3 item4 ;
     datalines ;
    1 0 1 0
    1 1 1 0
    1 0 1 0
    1 0 1 1;
```

As you know for the market basket analysis I want something like that:

```
           item1    item2    item3    item4

    item1   4         1       4        1
    item2   1         1       1        0
    item3   4         1       4        1
    item4   1         0       4        4
```

Any idea?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example WANT is incorrect.

```
data test;
   input item1-item4;
   datalines;
    1 0 1 0
    1 1 1 0
    1 0 1 0
    1 0 1 1
;;;;
proc print;
   run;
proc corr noprint sscp out=sscp(drop=int: where=(_type_ eq 'SSCP' and _NAME_ ne: 'Int'));
   var item:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]